# Undefined reference in opencv with devc++

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, dev-c++

I was trying to install opencv with devc++ on my windows system. I installed opencv and then added a new compiler in devc++.

I added the following command in calling the new compiler section

```
-L"C:\OpenCV\lib" -lcxcore210 -lcv210 -lcvaux210 -lhighgui210 -lml210
```

I added the follwing command for linker command line

```
-lcxcore210 -lcv210 -lcvaux210 -lhighgui210 -lml210
```

I added the corresponding opencv binaries,libraries and includes too and added opencv/bin to environment variables.

However when i try to run follwing opencv code,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;
#include "cv.h"
#include "highgui.h"
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
   cv::Mat img;

    getch();

}
```

It gives the following error.

> [Linker error]
>   C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ccGQvgqG.o:filename.cpp:(.text$_ZN2cv3Mat7releaseEv[cv::Mat::release()]+0x3f):
>   undefined reference to `cv::fastFree(void*)'

Comment: OpenCV 2.1.0 in 2016? Is this for real? Anyway, did you compile OpenCV with your compiler or are you trying to use prebuilt OpenCV libraries? Also, is this C or C++?

Comment: I am trying to use the prebuilt library. This is Opencv 2.10 as i could not make the 3.0 work. It gave the same issues. http://anikettatipamula.blogspot.com/2012/02/setting-up-opencv-on-dev-c.html This link was using 2.10 version so i though that would be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

### Please, **do not use OpenCV 2.1.0**.

Use OpenCV [2.4.13](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/releases/tag/2.4.13) or [3+](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/releases/tag/3.1.0).

As you can read in the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html#installation-in-windows):

> Prebuilt libraries [...] only works if you are coding with the latest Microsoft Visual Studio IDE.

If you want to use other compiler than Visual C++, you must build OpenCV libraries yourself. A good start is this [tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html#installation-by-making-your-own-libraries-from-the-source-files). Take care, because they are "long-obsolete and contain inaccurate information".